# Using PHP to display a folders contents, but show a message when folder is empty

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a intranet for my workplace and have used a bit of php I found online to scan the contents of the folder it's in and display them as links. It does this fine, but when it's inside an empty folder I would like it to display a message such as "There are no records matching those criteria.".

Is there a way to add something to the php to specify *if there are no folders listed print this*?

I have next to no knowledge of php, but html and css are no problem.

Here's the php I'm using in the page:

```
<?php
$dir=opendir(".");
$files=array();
while (($file=readdir($dir)) !== false)
{
    if ($file != "." and $file != ".." and $file != "A.php")
    {
        array_push($files, $file);
    }
}
closedir($dir);
sort($files);
foreach ($files as $file)
print "<div class='fileicon'>
           <a href='$file'>
               <img src='../../../images/TR-Icon.png'>
               <p class='filetext'>$file</p>
           </a>
      </div>";
?>
```

If you need anymore code such as the full page html or css just let me know.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:

After trying Josh's solution it pretty much nailed it, but I'm now getting "No files found" printing 3 times. Here's the code I'm using now:

```
<?php
$dir=opendir(".");
$files=array();
while (($file=readdir($dir)) !== false)
{   
if( count($files) == 0 )
{
echo '<p>No files found</p>';
}
else
{
if ($file != "." and $file != ".." and $file != "A.php")
{
array_push($files, $file);
}
}
}
closedir($dir);
sort($files);
foreach ($files as $file)
print " <div class='fileicon'>
<a href='$file'>
<img src='../../../images/TR-Icon.png'>
<p class='filetext'>$file</p>
</a>
</div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function to check if there are any files in your files array like this:

```
if(count($files) > 0) // check if there are any files in the files array
    foreach ($files as $file) // print the files if condition is true
        print " <a href='$file'>$file</a> <br />";
else 
    echo "ERROR!";
```

EDIT:

You can also use the [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function. However, this function will return two extra entries for *the current directory* and *directory up one level*. You need to remove these entries from the files array. Your code will look like this:

```
<?php
$dir   = "."; // the directory you want to check
$exclude = array(".", ".."); // you don't want these entries in your files array
$files = scandir($dir);
$files = array_diff($files, $exclude); // delete the entries in exclude array from your files array
if(!empty($files)) // check if the files array is not empty
{
    foreach ($files as $file) // print every file in the files array
        print " <div class='fileicon'>
<a href='$file'>
<img src='../../../images/TR-Icon.png'>
<p class='filetext'>$file</p>
</a>
</div>";
}
else 
{
    echo "There are no files in directory"; // print error message if there are noe files
}
?>
```

Comment: Care to add some comments to your code, why you propose this solution for example? How it works? Some link too

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that brings up an error when I implemented it, _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$file' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\filepath\A2.php on line 53_

Comment: @Yaroslav I edited my answer to make it more helpful. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @number8pie I'm not sure why that would be. But I _proposed_ a new solution.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you @imlokesh after adding _"A.php"_ to the $exclude array (so the php wouldn't pick up itself) it works a treat. Much appreciated my good man.

Answer (score 6):

Just do an:

```
if( count($files) == 0 )
{
  echo '<p>No files found</p>';
}
else
{
  // you have files
}
```

Comment: You can also make a : if (empty($files)) { echo '<p>No files found</p>'; } else {  // you have files }

Comment: Brilliant thanks for that, it works but it prints out "No files found" three times. Is there any way to kill the loop if there are no files found? I've changed the original post to show you what my code looks like now. Thanks again Josh.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
<?php
$dir=opendir(".");
$files=array();
while (($file=readdir($dir)) !== false)
{
    if ($file != "." and $file != ".." and $file != "A.php")
    {
        array_push($files, $file);
    }
}

closedir($dir);

if(count($files) == 0){
    die("There are no records matching those criteria.");
}else{
    sort($files);
    foreach ($files as $file)
        print " <div class='fileicon'>
                   <a href='$file'>
                       <img src='../../../images/TR-Icon.png'>
                       <p class='filetext'>$file</p>
                   </a>
                </div>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Eswar but the code bought up an error when there were no files (matching the criteria) in the folder. Here's the error code: _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$file' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\filepath\A2.php on line 53_

Comment: Please check the code again. I ran it and i don't have any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple conditional using `count` on your file array.

```
// ...
closedir($dir);
if (count($files) > 0) {
    // sort files and iterate through file array, printing html
} else {
    echo "There are no records matching those criteria.";
}
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it bought up an error: _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$file' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\filepath\A2.php on line 53_ It might be the way I'm implementing the code, I'm not sure like I mentioned I'm a complete php newb.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could let it print something else `if($files.length == 0)` and only print it normally `if($files.length > 0)` or something.

I have no knowledge of php, but I know java, html, css, and javascript.
I'm sure php has things like `array.length` (or something else to get the length of an array) in it

I hope this was helpful.

**EDIT**: I've seen others already answered thigs that are like 10x better than mine.
Also, php seems pretty cool, I might learn it

Comment: PHP looks awesome, but I'm torn between what to learn first PHP or jQuery. I'm leaning towards jQuery, but PHP is so next. Thanks for trying to help anyway.

Comment: I'd suggest PHP first. Whether you use plain Javascript or the jQuery enhancements in the browser, you almost always need to do server-side scripting. You can write reasonably nice pages without any Javascript at all.

Comment: I think you're right @Barmar, there's tons of plug-ins to do all kinds of tricks out there that are free to use to keep me going until I get my head around PHP. Thanks for the advice.