# Angularjs image carousel from selected folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dynamic-arrays

I wish to implement an image carousel based on the selected folder which the images are contained in. I am implementing AngularJS so as to get it to work but run into difficulties.

Please see below, my code so far which implements ajax.

How can I add PHP to my code to fetch all image files in a selected folder into an array which will be rendered as an image carousel?

Can someone please point me to any resource that can help me implement the PHP section?

I will like to know how to parse the "uri + currentFolder" to the php section and how to return the array of images back into the javascript section. Thank you

Here is an addition of the PHP File to fetch the images from folder

```
<?php
$path = $_REQUEST['imageFolder']; // path to images folder

$exclude = array(".", ".."); // I don't want these entries in my images array
$imagesArray = array(); //Declare empty array of images to be returned to javascript
$images = scandir($path); //Scan image directory and assign values to files variable

// check if there are any images in the in image directory
if(count($images) > 0){

    $images = array_diff($images, $exclude); //Declare new variable and assign all scanned images while excluding unwanted entries

    //Loop action for each image in the scanned collection
    foreach ($images as $image){
        //Push each images name into an array
        $imagesArray = $image;
        echo $imagesArray.'';
    }
        echo json_encode($imagesArray);
}

else {
    echo "No images found!";
}

?>
```

```js
(function () {
    function folderCtrl($scope) {
    //$scope.w = window.innerWidth;
    //$scope.h = window.innerHeight;
    $scope.uri = "img/gallery/";
    $scope.folders = ['sanitation-launch', 'cleanup-exercises',  'city-filth'];
    $scope.currentFolder = $scope.folders[0];
    $scope.selectFolder = function (folder) {
      $scope.currentFolder = folder;
    };
    $scope.activeFolder = function (folder) {
      return (folder === $scope.currentFolder);
    };
    
    var imageFolder = $scope.uri + $scope.currentFolder;
    //var imgArray = new array();
    
    $scope.images = function (){
        $.post('media-carousel.php', imageFolder, function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key, val){
                $scope.images.push(val);
            });
        });
    };
    
     console.log('images list '+$scope.images); 
     console.log ('where is my '+imageFolder);
     console.log ($scope.currentFolder + ' is selected');
        
  }
    angular
        .module('media-carousel', [])
        .controller('folderCtrl', folderCtrl);
})();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div ng-app="media-carousel">
              <div class="container" ng-controller="folderCtrl">      
                <!-- Carousel
                      ================================================== -->
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <!-- Indicators -->
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" ng-repeat="img in images" ng-class="{active: (img === 0)}" data-slide-to="{{img}}"></li>
                  </ol>
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div ng-class="{item: true, active: (img === 0)}" ng-repeat="img in images">
                      <img ng-src="{{uri}}/{{currentFolder}}/{{img}}" alt="Clean Ghana Sanitation  {{img}}">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                </div><!-- /.carousel -->

                <!-- Fixed navbar -->
                <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-botom" role="navigation">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li ng-repeat="folder in folders" ng-class="{active:activeFolder(folder)}" ng-click="selectFolder(folder)">
                          <a ng-href="#{{folder}}">{{folder}}</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't see bootstrap.js or carousel.js..also, any errors in the console? Hard to say what the issue is if all you say is it doesn't work

Comment: Does your server allow you to see what's in a directory from the browser? Not a safe practice if it does and you you normally read directories using a server side programming language

Comment: @Ronnie : I have added bootstrap.js now. Unfortunately, there are no errors shown in the console but the array is empty. Could there be an issue with the ajax bit of my code where it loops to populate the array?

Comment: @Charlietfl: I haven't deployed to a server just yet, just running from my local pc at the moment. I, however, will like to adopt safe practices which will require me using PHP or other server-side languages. The issue is I don't know how to implement it. If my reasoning is right, I will be sending the directory path to the PHP section depending on the selected folder and then return an array for the list of files in the directory back into the javascript. Can you please show me how to do that?

Comment: Voted to close because this is like 5 or 10 questions in 1.  You should look into and use $http not $.ajax when using angular (it effectively does the same thing but hooks into triggering the view to update).  For the PHP side or server side there are lots of tutorials on setting up the basics to do exactly as you describe in your comment but no sign of work done on that side yet.  Please give the PHP or other server side a shot and post your results here if you run into a specific problem you can't find a solution for.

Comment: Some other things to note for interactive components from bootstrap use ui-bootstrap angular module/directives instead of bootstrap.js and jquery.  The ui-bootstrap module has all the functionality needed in most cases or can be extended to work well with angular, having things outside of directives manipulating the DOM will cause problems.  For ui-bootstrap just include the ui-bootstrap-tpls.js file and bootstrap.css file (no other JS needed).

Comment: @shaunhusain: can you please point me to any resource that can help me implement the PHP section? I will like to know how to parse the "uri + currentFolder" to the php section and how to return the array of images back into the javascript section. Thank you

Comment: @Selase https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710201/using-php-to-display-a-folders-contents-but-show-a-message-when-folder-is-empty  I'm personally a fan of using something like laravel/lumen/slim to handle the server side routing.  Laravel is overkill for small projects but once you get used to using ORM it is very helpful, Laravel also includes server side routing config (Lumen just gives you the routing part but less of the other providers and ORM parts... called Illuminate).  Slim is an alternative PHP framework for setting up routes/handlers.

Comment: Only downside I see with laravel is it prescribes having the backend create views using "blade" files their own templating language but this isn't ideal IMO the server side should just be a REST API that deals with data and the client is completely separate static angular site that consumes the data from the API (and/or posts data via the API, this setup is possible with laravel but requires some extra thought).  Search around on google or youtube lots of walk throughs on setting up laravel and understanding the basics, it's again just too much to cover in comments or a single answer here.

Comment: @shaunhusain: I have updated my codes by including the php file. when i run the php code with a static value for path it returns the array of images in the said folder. However, when i set it dynamically for the path to be sent from javascript and for array to be returned to javascript it does not seem to work and i dont get any error codes in the console either.